# File location for Syslogs in Centos machine

Tags: linux, centos, syslog, rsyslog

I am running syslog server (rsyslog 8) on my centos machine. I want to map other device in my network to send the logs to this syslog server. If mapping is done correctly where exactly the syslogs will get stored in centos machine. `/var/log/messages` folder ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) is a standard logging facility. It collects messages of various programs and services including the kernel, and stores them, depending on setup, in a bunch of log files typically under `/var/log`. In some datacenter setups there are *hundreds* of devices each with its own log; **syslog** comes here handy too. One just sets up a dedicated syslog server which collects all the individual device logs over the network. Syslog can also save logs to databases, and other stuff.

According to my `/etc/syslog.conf`, default `/var/log/kern.log` captures only the kernel's messages of any loglevel; i.e. the output of `dmesg`.

`/var/log/messages` instead aims at storing valuable, non-debug and non-critical messages. This log should be considered the "general system activity" log.

`/var/log/syslog` in turn logs everything, except auth related messages.

Other insteresting standard logs managed by syslog are `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/mail.log`.

Regarding your question : `/var/log/messages` is not a folder.